# Reading from a file in different threads in C

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I have a multithreaded server program where each thread is required to read the contents of a file to retrieve data requested by the client.

I am using pthreads in C to accomplish creating a thread and passing the function the thread which the thread will execute.

In the function, if I assign to a new `FILE` pointer with `fopen()` and subsequently read the contents of the file with `fgets()`, will each thread have its own file offset? That is, if thread 1 is reading from the file, and it is on line 5 of the file when thread 2 reads for the first time, does thread 2 start reading at line 5 or is it independent of where thread 1 is in the file?

Comment: Consider `mmap()`ing the file and then passing it as read-only to the threads.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each open `FILE` has only one file pointer. That has one associated FD, and one file position (file offset as you put it).

But you can `fopen` the file twice (from two different threads or for that matter from the same thread) - as your edit now implies you are doing. That means you'll have two associated FDs and two separate file positions.

IE, this has nothing to do with threads per se, just that if you want separate file positions, you will need two FDs which (with stdio) means two `FILE`s.

Comment: See the edit. I meant that I'm opening a `FILE` in the function, so each thread opens its own `FILE`.

Comment: All the comments are accurate as long as you don't go futzing with `dup()` or `dup2()` (or `fcntl()`'s DUP) on the `fileno(fp)` from a particular `FILE *`. It's possible to break things, but you have to go out of your way to do so. Even if you use the low-level file descriptor I/O, each `open()` call gives you a new file descriptor referencing a new open file description, and the read/write position is associated with the open file description. Again, as long as you don't go dinking with `dup2()` and no two threads are simultaneously using the same file descriptor, there won't be any trouble.